# android searchview show suggestions list

Tags: android, media, searchview

I am trying to create a music app and want to show suggestions dropdown in search view in the app bar. I followed the instructions from the developer android [site](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/search/search-dialog). I have created a searchable xml file, a custom provider that extends the SearchRecentSuggestionsProvider.

public class SearchProvider extends SearchRecentSuggestionsProvider{

```
public final static String AUTHORITY = "com.example.providers.SearchRecentSuggestionsProvider";
public final static int MODE = DATABASE_MODE_QUERIES;

public SearchProvider(){
    setupSuggestions(AUTHORITY,MODE);
}
```

}

I am able to show the search view in the app bar.But now I am stuck as to what should I do next. I have to show the results from the MediaStore content provider.

Comment: use `SearchView#setSuggestionsAdapter` with `SimpleCursorAdapter` and setup its `FilterQueryProvider`

Comment: I have never used SimpleCursorAdapter so I will try to implement it and let know if its worked.If you can provide any link that might be helpful.Thanks

Comment: as always: www.google.com

Comment: It worked. Thanks

Comment: good! as for someone who never used it, I'm really impressed